# Hamburger menu not showing in Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use `nav` and  `nav-bar` in `Bootstrap3`.

```
<div id="gnav" class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="" >
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

Can I prevent showing the hamburger menu on small device widths?

Instead of the menu, I want to show texts like home, items, contact and so on, like in the desktop view.

[Here’s](http://takeshi-du.github.io/Bootstrap3-tutorials/) an example of the behaviour I do not want.

Comment: Hamburger menu?

Comment: @PawanNogariya he means the collapsed menu opened on a button click (usually with the 3 bars icon, the "hamburger") &#9776;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Check Demo [**HERE**](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/xEzbrr?editors=1100)

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>


    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only ">(current)</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>


  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav::after,
.nav::before,
.navbar-header::after,
.navbar::after {
  display: table-caption;
}

.nav.navbar-nav li,
.nav.navbar-nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Jyoti. I realized `class="collapse navbar-collapse` was problem on my code. And Thank you for your `css`.